# how to apply Pagination on post

Tags: pagination

My English is bad so sorry for that ,I want to apply Pagination  to my blog page ,I want to display 3 post on page  then want to apply Pagination .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A siple search on google got me to these websites:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

These are Wordpress Tutorials for setting pagination.

You can also install a plugin, I recommend WP PageNavi. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/